# Making a 2 coloumn table with PHP without 'echoing' so much

Tags: php, html, sql

I am working with PHP and My SQL to get data from an SQL database and show it in 2 columns.

I have figured out how to do it with the code as below. However I am working with a complex HTML template and don't want to echo every single HTML line to get it work - It will be very complicated to read and fix if there is an issue!

```
<table>
<?php
$i = 0;

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>

         <?php if (++$i % 2 != 0)  echo "<tr>";?>



       <?php  echo "<td>" .$row['fname']."</td>"; ?>


        <?php   if ($i % 2 == 0); 
                } if ($i % 2 != 0); ?>

    <td></td></tr>
</table>
```

I have simplified the template as below. Here I am 'echoing' within the HTML which I find easier to read and understand:

```
<div class=container>
    <div id="fname"><a>First Name:</a><?php echo $row['fname'];?></div>
    <div id="website"><a>Website:</a><?php echo $row['website'];?></div>

</div>
```

To summarize, is it possible to take my data from the database and show it in 2 columns without having to echo every single HTML line. Keeping my HTML structure similar to the above?

The column layout I am try to achieve is as below:

```
1 | 2
-----
3 | 4
-----
5 | 6
-----
```

I have not been able to find an example anywhere!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are advantages to writing HTML out in PHP script and there are also advantages to breaking into PHP from your HTML script.  It really just depends on the circumstances.

For example if I am writing html that is generated from loops of has alot of variable inputs I will write the HTML inside the PHP.  However, If I am writing a big chunk of HTML with only a few variables I will break into PHP from the HTML.

It really just depends on the circumstances.

That being said, when writing HTML from inside of PHP I will break it down and concatenate the HTML as much as possible.  That way I am not breaking in and out of PHP to get the task accomplished.  The more you code the easier that will get.

Below is how I would write your code.  Notice I never broke in and out of PHP.

```
echo
'<table>';

$i = 0;

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

  echo 
  '<tr>';

    echo 
    '<td>' . $row['fname'] . '</td>' .
    '<td>' . $row['lname'] . '</td>';

  echo
  '</tr>';
}  

echo
'</table>';
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for advising me! As I have a lot of HTML how would I structure the code when using my template above - with the inline php echo while creating a 2 column table?

Comment: I have updated the code to give you two columns a row.   All that I did was add another `<td>` tag.  Also I removed the if statements that are using the mod.  Those would be used if you needed to alternate something for every other row.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in PHP, just another very simple option.

```
$str = '';    
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $str .= '<tr><td>'.$row['value1'].'</td><td>'.$row['value2'].'</td></tr>';
}
```

I don't know all the correct keys in the $row, but I think you get the idea.

And than the HTML would be like this:

```
<table>
  <?php echo $str; ?>
</table>
```

Just a little hint. You can google on a MVC construction. This stands for Model View Controller and it is in my opinion the best way to keep your code organised.